# Multithreading - One long thread vs many little threads

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have an application that has 3 unique tasks that need to be executed once per second and need to run in parallel. I made the application to have 3 long running threads, basically a thread with a while True and it only breaks when the application is stopped.

I have a Java developer friend that suggested instead to make the task perform then stop and basically execute the same function over and over again, essentially creating a new thread each second. The while True is outside of the threads and creates them over and over. The idea being that if for some reason one dies or hangs, it doesn't cause issues. Any unforeseen errors, the next second it moves on and tries again. I like this idea but it's slightly harder to implement.

Curious what is the best approach for Python:

1. 3 long running threads that loop inside the thread
2. 1 while loop that creates new threads each second

One last note, I need to have some data that carries over each run, so for #2 I would have a class created and a class method would be called as a thread.

#2 would look something like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        print('Test')
        self.counter += 1

test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
    while True:
        t1 = executer.submit(test1.run)
        t2 = executer.submit(test2.run)
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Threads don't randomly die or hang without reasons. And thread creation can be pretty expensive

Comment: Why not use a timer instead? I'm not sure about Python's implementation, but in some cases it avoids the complications that multithreading brings (race conditions, deadlocks, synchronization overhead). In any case, "once every second" is probably not a performance issue.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks my example is using the thread pool executor. But I understand the idea of overhead in creating and destroying threads. Also as mentioned it's proving to be more complicated than starting and monitoring a thread.

Comment: Comment withdrawn.